# php textarea unable to make it a string with no spaces tabs or enterkeys

Tags: php, textarea, implode, removing-whitespace

Well this is my problem i am not able to make a string out of the array... i want it to only have numbers and commas, i have a function for that but it recieves  a string and by some reason i am not able to convert it to a string only in this case can you help me?

this is my code...

```
$notes = explode("\n", $_POST['numeros']);
$data = implode($notes);
preg_replace("/\s\s+/", " ", $data);
$validanum = validanum($data);
```

the string its not generated by this numbers that i copied and pasted to the corresponding textarea...

95546900,
89917266,
95767373,
95559742,
99348203,
95045759,
88638749,
97816260,
98743612,
97598895,
31899524,
98051344,
95763339,
96416568,
95559843,
97275729,
95546900,
99094356,
99217192,
95381641,
95528828

thanks in advanced...

Comment: Don't you mean `$data = implode($notes);` ?

Comment: yes sorry i copied it wrong... ill update

Comment: So, where are you having the issue? Is `$notes` an array? Is `$data` a string? What is `preg_replace` returning, and shouldn't you be assigning it to a variable?

Comment: ok look $_POST['numeros'] its what my textarea haves but i tried to treat it as an array but it says it is not an array so thats why i am trying to explode it but once i do these and then implode it because i need it as a string i would only make the first number... dont know why... but this issue its only with this numbers.... i am sorry if you feel i am doing something stupid ... haha but i am new at this...

Comment: you're not doing anything stupid; I'm trying to figure out where the error is happening. After you set each variable, can you check to see that it has the right value? Just `echo` out the contents to see what it contains.

Comment: haha ok i think i am getting closer at the end this is what i get from an echo > 12341234< i shouldn't be getting that white space at the begining of the string... i think this its not making its "work"
 $num = preg_replace('\s+/',' ', $item);
that is suppose to remove all white spaces.... thank you very much for your help i really appreciate it

Comment: try `$num = preg_replace ('/\s+/', '', $item);` - I think it's missing the initial slash. If that doesn't work, could you update your question with your current code, please?

Comment: You're welcome - glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that newline symbol is \r\n not only \n so you can try changing:

```
$notes = explode("\n", $_POST['numeros']);
```

to

```
$notes = explode("\r\n", $_POST['numeros']);
```

You can also show results of explode by using:

```
print_r($notes);
```

And you should double check what you are really exploding and imploding.

Functions echo and/or print_r should be helpful here.